# Yet another dice game

Tags: probability, dice

I'm doing a little self study in probability theory and read about the coupon collector's problem, which lead me to think about the following dice game:

Suppose you have seven regular fair 6-sided dice, labeled $d_0, ..., d_6$.  In each round of the game first $d_0$ is rolled.  Let's say it lands on $i$; then $d_i$ is rolled.

I'm interested in the number of rounds until all six sides of all seven dice have been rolled (at least once).  How would I go about analyzing this situation?  In particular, how can I find the distribution of number of rounds and/or what is the expected value?

What about the variation where I'm just interested in rolling a particular side (say, 6) of all seven dice?  And what if we generalize to a $k$-sided "selector" die that chooses which $n$-sided die to roll?  As you can probably tell, I'm completely stuck on these problems.

For a single die the situation is easier; it's just the coupon collector's problem, or for the mentioned variation, the number of Bernoulli trials needed for one success with $p = 1/6$.  But as soon as I introduce a second die (and a coin flip to choose between them), the problem seems to become much more complicated, let alone the situation described above.

I've tried to read up on probability generating functions, but so far I haven't been able to tackle the problem.  I've also tried modeling the problem as a Markov process, but that seems intractable for dice with more sides.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is this not just a $6^6$-sided fair die? Every side of every die has an even chance of being rolled in each round. This sounds like the coupon collector's problem, just with a bigger number.

Comment: @TheoBendit I think, the given problem is different. We can see every number in every position even if not all combinations occured. For example, seven ones , seven twos ... seven sixes would satisfy the desired outcome.

Comment: @TheoBendit yes, you're right, except that it would be a $6^2$ sided die (six faces times six labels).  Now I feel stupid for asking the question.  Also, the variation of the game is then just the coupon collector's problem with $n = 36$ coupons of which $k = 5 \times 6$ have already been collected.  This also aligns with my simulations.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad my not-very-well-thought-out comment helped in some way.

Comment: @TheoBendit Could you make your comment an answer?

Comment: @HighDiceRoller I'm not familiar enough with the coupon collector's problem to be confident in an answer. I think br0ns would be the better choice to author an answer.